# how can we save in vs code , the semicolon keeps showing after each line while updating while using mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, server

How can we save in vs code using a macbkpro? the semicolon keeps showing  after each line while updating after saving the files. (prettier is running in the background and currently and I am setting up a server)does any of that conflict with vs code? I tried **cntl s**, **cmmd s** still getting same errors after stopped the server and reinitialized.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how do you get rid of the semicolons that are appearing after each line in vscode?